# Relationship between AWS S3 and AWS Elastic Beanstalk(multi-docker env)

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need some clarification on the concept/relationship of AWS Elastic Beanstalk and AWS S3.

If I am creating an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance with multiple docker containers(two: one frontend, one backend) env, in my AWS S3 basket, should I have one zip file for both frontend and backend container, or should I have separate zip files for each docker container??

Thanks!

Comment: You should have separate zip files for each docker container.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html
Section: containerDefinitions -> An array of container definitions, detailed below.